# Amazon MWS DateTime issue depending how initalized

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am requesting a report from Amazon MWS using their SDK (https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/reports/v20090101/cSharp.html). I am calling Request Report (http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_RequestReport.html). I have to submit a start and end date. The issue I am running into is the SDK won't accept my DateTime input if initialized a certain way but does the other way and I can't understand why that is.

Here is my code. When I initialize using DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14) it does NOT work. When I initialize by setting a specific date, new DateTime(2019, 1, 23) it DOES work. When I run both through LINQPad the structure looks the same to me.

The commented code does not work. The code right after does.

```
MarketplaceWebServiceConfig config = new MarketplaceWebServiceConfig();
            config.ServiceURL = "https://mws.amazonservices.com";

            MarketplaceWebServiceClient service =
                new MarketplaceWebServiceClient(
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretKey"],
                    "Easy MWS Reports",
                    "1.0",
                    config);

            RequestReportRequest request = new RequestReportRequest();
            request.Merchant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SellerId"];
            request.MarketplaceIdList = new IdList();
            request.MarketplaceIdList.Id = new List<string>( new string [] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MarketplaceId"] } );

            request.ReportType = "_GET_AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENTS_DATA_";

            //request.StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14);
            //request.EndDate = DateTime.Today;
            request.StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 6);
            request.EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 2, 5);

            RequestReportResponse response = service.RequestReport(request);
```

The really strange thing is when I inspect the request object before calling the API my start and end dates are correct. When I get that response back Amazon is telling me my start and end dates are both .Now. That leads me to believe that DateTime objects are serializing different based on how I initialize them and that I don't understand.

[UPDATE] I beleive eitamal is correct but there doesn't seem to be any way to do that that is easier then what I settled on which is the following.

```
var then = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-15);
var now = DateTime.Today;
request.StartDate = new DateTime(then.Year, then.Month, then.Day);
request.EndDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day);
```

Comment: I still don't know what this is working this way but I put a band-aid on it for now by doing: var then = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-20);
            var now = DateTime.Today;
            request.StartDate = new DateTime(then.Year, then.Month, then.Day);
            request.EndDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day);

Comment: can you use Fiddler and examine the POST that the SDK does for you?  Run it with AddDays(-14) and then with the manually created DateTime, look for differences in the parameters.  I'm curious too!

Comment: I just did that. The SDK is sending the wrong StartDate and EndDate. So the issue seems to be the SDK. The SDK is open source. I tried to follow the path of the code. Nothing stands out to me. Here is the post data for the call. StartDate=2019-02-06T20%3A00%3A50.052Z&EndDate=2019-02-06T20%3A00%3A50.052Z

Comment: Could it be related to the `Kind` of `DateTime`? i.e. when you use the `new` syntax, you're not specifying the kind which would set it to the default (`Unspecified`), and when you're using the `Today` syntax, by default, it'll have a kind of `Local`. While the `POST` call you've posted contains a format stating that its kind is `Utc`.

Comment: That makes sense eitamal.  Can you create a UTC date first and then add(-14) to that.  Or convert the Local DateTime to UTC after subtracting 14.

Comment: That is probably the issue. I don't see a way to use that that is easier then what I am using now (my first response to myself). I don't see any way to construct a DateTime then change to UTC. Thank you for all the input.